# React routing not working

Tags: reactjs, url-routing

I'm beginner of react. When I put Route tag I'm getting the error like below-attached image!.  Anyone know about this, kindly tell me the answer.

[image]

Here is my JSX code below.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route} from 'react-router';

class Home extends Component {
    render(){
        return (<h1>Hi123</h1>);
    }
}

render(
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Here is my package file

```
  {
  "name": "routing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "routing test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack -d --watch",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "nodemon",
    "serve": "serve ./public",
    "dev"  : "webpack-dev-server --content-base src --inline --hot"
  },
  "author": "VJ",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "serve": "^5.0.2",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "history": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-router": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a browserHistory attribute to your  tag. Append your code like so:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

class Home extends Component {
    render(){
        return (<h1>Hi123</h1>);
    }
}

render(
    <Router history={history}>
        <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

For a bit more info on the browserHistory attribute, [check out react-router's API docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router/history-object).

Comment: @vijayaganth - my fault, I was using the old API. I just looked up the new one and updated my code. See above.

Comment: Now i'm getting this error in node cmd "con't resolve history/createBrowserHistory"

Comment: @vijayaganth go to your node cmd and type "npm install --save history". That should resolve your error.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact same problem earlier today. I did a little research and it appears react-router has had a little update. I switched to 'react-router-dom' instead, and followed the new docs here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

That solved the problem. So, delete this from your node_modules, and replace this line in your package.json file:

```
"react-router": "^4.0.0"
```

By using this instead:

```
"react-router-dom": "^4.0.0"
```

(Rolling back to an earlier version of react-router might also solve the issue.) If you do update to react-router-dom, definitely check out the docs. You'll need to use BrowserRouter as Router when you import... the BrowserRouter appears to eliminate the need to add the browserHistory as an attribute of the Router component.